# Testing Watchers in Vue.js with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jasmine

I want to test a VueJS watcher method, to check if it's called. My method looks like:

```
watch: {
   value: (newValue, oldValue) {
     if (newValue.Status === 'Completed') {
        ...do somethind
     }
  }
}
```

The method is working when the value is changed the method is fired, but on the test is not fired.

My test looks like:

```
var propsData = {
   "value" : {
      "Status" : "Something"
    }
}
it('should call method', done => {
   const Constructor = Vue.extend(App);
   const spy = sinon.spy(App, 'value');
   const vm = new Constructor({ propsData: propsData }).$mount();
   vm.value.Status = 'Completed';
   Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
      done()
   })
})
```

I found the following examples, but it seems are not working on my case:

1. [Asserting Asynchronous Updates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html#Asserting-Asynchronous-Updates)
2. [Forum](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/09/18/Test-Computed-Properties-and-Watchers-in-Vue-js-Components-with-Jest/)

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `value.Status`, not actually `value` reference. To make watch trigger on value change, you can use `deep: true`

```
watch: {
   value: {
     handler: (newValue, oldValue) {
       this.checkValue() 
     },
     deep: true
   }
},
methods: {
  checkValue() {
  }
}
```

and then

```
it('should call method', done => {
   const Constructor = Vue.extend(App);
   const vm = new Constructor({ propsData: propsData }).$mount();
   const spy = sinon.spy(vm, 'checkValue');
   vm.value.Status = 'New value';
   vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
      done()
   })
})
```

Comment: It's my mistake. there should be `value`. I made an update.

Comment: Where do you declare `someMethod`?

Comment: I made an update on my question. I don't have `someMethod`, the watcher name should be equal with the parameter what is watched.

Comment: I receive the following error after making all changes you suggested: `Attempted to wrap undefined property checkValue as function`

Comment: New error after changes: `Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172046/discussion-between-ittus-and-kutas-tomy).